# Proxy setting for F-Secure SSH on Windows 7

Tags: windows, ssh, mercurial, tortoisehg, libssh2

For TortoiseHg we are using F-Secure SSH (company decision) for authentication. We can access all the repo's with in company's network, but when i try to access bit-bucket it fails.

I tried accessing bit-bucket with https settings (https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/reponame) and it worked after setting the proxy in mercurial.ini

```
[http_proxy]
host = proxy-us.xxx.com:xxx
user = xxx
```

How can i do the same for SSH?  I could see few settings for doing it through putty, but I'm not able to get the details for F-Secure SSH (ssh2).

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to `%USERPROFILE%\mercurial.ini`:

```
[ui]
ssh = "C:\Program Files (x86)\F-Secure\Ssh\ssh2.exe" -o "SocksServer proxy.internal:1080"
```

Comment: _remote: warning: Connecting to bitbucket.org failed: TCP/IP Failure_    is the warning i'm getting with the above changes

Comment: Your proxy server may be refusing connections.  The proxy server for F-Secure ssh2 needs to be a SOCKS proxy, and not HTTP(S) proxy.